# Resending data in socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, virtual-machine, smb

So I'm trying to send multiple packets over and over again to my VM, but after one attempt, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SMB_Test2.py", line 157, in <module>
    s.sendall(SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

which I presume is due to repeated malformed data being sent (on purpose), but I want to know if and how there is a way around that. I'm essentially looking to repeatedly send that SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE many times. Thanks in advance.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((addr, port))
s.settimeout(2)

print '[*] Connected to "%s:%d".' % (addr, port)
s.sendall(SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE)
a = 0
while a != 50000:
    print a
    a = a + 1
    s.sendall(SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE)
    print '[*] Sent to "%s:%d".' % (addr, port)
```

EDIT (off Jame's suggestion) - Still jumps right to an error:

```
a = 0
try:
    print "The value of 'a' is %r." % a
    s.connect((addr, port))
    print '[*] Connected to "%s:%d".' % (addr, port)
    while a != 50000:
        a = a + 1
        s.sendall(SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE)
        print '[*] Sent to "%s:%d".' % (addr, port)
        print "The value 'a' is %r." % a
except:
    print "[-] An error occured!!!"
    s.close()
    exit()
```

Output:

```
The value of 'a' is 0.
[*] Connected to "192.168.xxx.xxx:xxx".
[*] Sent to "192.168.xxx.xxx:xxx".
The value 'a' is 1.
[-] An error occured!!!
```

Also tried this (almost identical):

```
a = 0
print "The value of 'a' is %r." % a
s.connect((addr, port))
print '[*] Connected to "%s:%d".' % (addr, port)
def ok():
    try:
        while a != 50000:
            a = a + 1
            s.sendall(SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE)
            print '[*] Sent to "%s:%d".' % (addr, port)
            print "The value 'a' is %r." % a
    except:
        print "[-] An error occured!!!"
        sleep(0)
        s.close()
```

Which had an output (not even sending anything):

```
The value of 'a' is 0.
[*] Connected to "192.168.xxx.xxx:xxx".
[-] An error occurred!!!
```

Comment: catch the exception, close the socket, get a new socket and connect again. Look up any of the millions of articles on try/except in python. [Here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/error-handling/python-try-and-except) is one.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Updated

Comment: well, obviously the "get a new socket and connect again" needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: @JamesKPolk When you say "get a new socket and connect again", are you referring to a completly new addr + port or closing the socket and connecting back to it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code fragment to illustrate my comment.

```
import socket

def try_connect():
    """Tries to connect and send the SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE bytes.
       Returns the socket object on success and None on failure.
    """
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(2)
    try:
        s.connect((addr, port))
        s.sendall(SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE)
    except socket.timeout as e:
        # got a socket timeout
        return None
    except OSError as e:
        # got some other socket error
        return None
    return s

def try_connect_n_times(n):
    """Try up to n times to connect"""
    for attempt in range(n):
        s = try_connect()
        if s:
            return s
    return None

try_connect_n_times(5000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful post, worked exactly as I wanted it to after I removed for s = and if s: return s. Thanks for your time and help, greatly appreciated :).

Comment: Side question if you're interested: I want a new s.sendall(SMB_COM_NEGOTIATE) to be sent each time its called. I've tried calling it with a def but that didn't work (as analyzed in wireshark). ideas?